# Using files I downloaded with python

Tags: python, web, python-requests

So I want to download a bunch of clinical trial information from clinicaltrials.gov. They have a system that lets you download searches by using a custom URL. The url format is https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/download_fields?cond=&term=genentech&locn=pennsylvania&down_count=1000&down_fmt=xml

First of all how do I download that file using python? I'm assuming its something like

`file = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/download_fields?cond=&term=genentech&locn=pennsylvania&down_count=1000&down_fmt=xml')`

Then can I also rename the file and put it in my working directory?

In the end I would like to process about three to four hundred downloads and parse the files for certain information. I think I can handle that part but getting all the files into my working directory is what I'm having trouble with now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That returns you a requests.response object. Call file.text to get the text content of the response and then you can parse that with an xml parser.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: No worries. Docs for requests: [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)